# Which ultrafilters are (sort-of) commutators?

Tags: general-topology, logic, set-theory, semigroups, universal-algebra

There is a natural way to extend a binary operation $\star$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ to a semicontinuous binary operation $\widehat{\star}$ on $\beta\mathbb{Z}$, the latter being the set of ultrafilters on $\mathbb{Z}$; see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427135/what-algebraic-properties-are-preserved-by-mathbbn-leadsto-beta-mathbbn) *(replacing $\mathbb{N}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ as appropriate)*. In general, algebraic properties of $\star$ are not preserved by this extension - e.g. $\widehat{+}$ has nontrivial idempotents and is non-commutative - but this extension can nonetheless be useful.

I'm interested in understanding *how* noncommutative $\widehat{+}$ is (right now, the best result I know is that [it has trivial center](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87846/28111)). Normally one might attack this sort of question by looking at the commutator subgroup of $(\beta\mathbb{Z};\widehat{+})$, but since $\widehat{+}$ is non-cancellative this doesn't make sense. We can however whip up a "brute force" analogue by considering $\widehat{+}$ **and** $\widehat{-}$ explicitly. This leads to the following:

> **Question 1**: Is every nonprincipal ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ equal to $$[(\mathcal{W}_1\widehat{+}\mathcal{W}_2)\widehat{-}\mathcal{W}_1]\widehat{-}\mathcal{W}_2$$ for some ultrafilters $\mathcal{W}_1,\mathcal{W}_2$ on $\mathbb{Z}$?

Of course, this is a rather naive attempt to whip up a commutator-like notion:

> **Question 2**: Is there a more useful analogue of the notion of commutator when looking at non-cancellative semigroups (namely $(\beta\mathbb{Z};\widehat{+})$)?

I know that there is [a lot of universal algebra around generalized commutator theory](http://math.hawaii.edu/%7Eralph/Commutator/comm.pdf), but to my limited understanding it works best when the algebra in question is (say) congruence modular, and it's not clear to me whether $(\beta\mathbb{Z};\widehat{+})$ is congruence modular.

Comment: Ok I'm too tired to think about $\widehat{-}$, which turned out to be a far uglier operation than I expected. I'll remove my previous comments to tidy up. I still expect the answer to be negative (more precisely I still expect that the set of elements that can be written as such a commutator is very small)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Here's a fun question which might be hard enough to ask on its own: which $\mathcal{A}\in\beta(\mathbb{Z})$ satisfy $\exists\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{U}\widehat{-}\mathcal{U}=\mathcal{A})$? (Call these "pseudo-zero.") I don't think they're just the principle ultrafilter generated by $\{0\}$ ...

Comment: My gut feeling is that there is no way it is only $0$, but I have no proof