# Reducing a double ultrapower to a single ultrapower

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, filters

I hate having to ask this question, as I know for a fact I have seen the answer before but cannot seem to find it.  So I'm breaking down and asking for a reference.

---

Given a structure, let's say a Banach space $E$, and two ultrafilters $\mathfrak{U}$, and $\mathfrak{V}$ on $I$ and $J$ respectively.

We may of course form the Banach space Ultrapower $(E)_{\mathfrak{U}}$ which again gives a Banach space.  If we then take the ultrapower again, with respect to $\mathfrak{V}$, we get $[(E)_{\mathfrak{U}}]_{\mathfrak{V}}$.

I have seen (I am almost certain it was in the form of either an answer or a comment on this site) an argument that we can write $[(E)_{\mathfrak{U}}]_{\mathfrak{V}} = (E)_{\mathfrak{W}}$ for an appropriately defined ultrapower $\mathfrak{W}$ on $I\times J$.

I was wondering if anyone can provide a reference to the details of this?

Comment: In http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/thesis.pdf, it is established that the cartesian product of two ultrafilters is again an ultrafilter.  So that would pose as an strong candidate for $\mathfrak{W}$.  But I still can't find the reduction property that I'm seeking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $x=\langle x^{(j)}:j\in J\rangle\in (E^I)^J$, where each $x^{(j)}=\langle x_i^{(j)}:i\in I\rangle\in E^I$. Similarly, let $y=\langle y^{(j)}:j\in J\rangle\in (E^I)^J$, where each $y^{(j)}=\langle y_i^{(j)}:i\in I\rangle\in E^I$. Then we want to define $\mathfrak{W}$ so that

$$\begin{align*}
x_{\mathfrak{W}}=y_{\mathfrak{W}}\quad&\text{iff}\quad\left\{j\in J:{x^{(j)}}_{\mathfrak{U}}={y^{(j)}}_{\mathfrak{U}}\right\}\in\mathfrak{V}\\
&\text{iff}\quad\left\{j\in J:\left\{i\in I:x_i^{(j)}=y_i^{(j)}\right\}\in\mathfrak{U}\right\}\in\mathfrak{V}\;.
\end{align*}$$

The ultrafilter product $\mathfrak{V}\cdot\mathfrak{U}$ is the ultrafilter on $J\times I$ such that for each $W\subseteq J\times I$,

$$W\in\mathfrak{V}\cdot\mathfrak{U}\quad\text{iff}\quad\big\{j\in J:\{i\in I:\langle j,i\rangle\in W\}\in\mathfrak{U}\big\}\in\mathfrak{V}\;.$$

From this it’s not hard to see that you want

$$\mathfrak{W}=\{\langle i,j\rangle\in I\times J:\langle j,i\rangle\in\mathfrak{V}\cdot\mathfrak{U}\}\;.$$

The ultrafilter product that I’ve written $\mathfrak{V}\cdot\mathfrak{U}$ is denoted by $\otimes$ in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31147/sum-and-product-of-ultrafilters?rq=1); it is a special case of what is sometimes called the *Fubini* (or *tensor*) *product* of ultrafilters, and searching on that term will bring up assorted references; one that’s on the web, rather than a PDF or PostScript file, is [here](http://boolesrings.org/krautzberger/2011/01/09/eternal-preliminaries-part-2-filters-and-ultrafilters/).